# Replacing content in Jquery with If / Else condition

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a table which has some cells in, one cell has a 0 in so I want to change that to a No, the other has a 1 in so I want to change that to a Yes but I cannot seem to get it working, here is what I have thus far:

```
if ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text('0')) {

    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').html('No');

} elseif ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text('1')) {

    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').html('Yes');

}
```

Am I missing something? I can't use val as these aren't form areas

Comment: just an optimization tip: since you call it so often, set `$('.fsAction td:eq(2)')` to a variable so your element only has to be found once.

Answer (score 3):

`.text()` will get the text value, and `'.text('0')` will set the text to '0'. try comparing the text.

```
if ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text() === '0') {

    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').html('No');

} elseif ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text() === '1') {

    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').html('Yes');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two problems here. Either your selector is bad, or your method is bad. I'd try to eliminate the possibility of a selector issue by adding a class name to the table cell in question and doing just

```
if ($('.tablecelltest').text() == '0') {
    $('.tablecelltest').html('No');
} 
elseif ($('.tablecelltest').text() == '1') {
    $('.tablecelltest').html('Yes');
}
```

If that doesn't work, you have a selector issue. I might try this, as sometimes a pure text selector will give me trouble:

```
$('.fsAction').find('td').eq(2)
```

If that doesn't work, we'd probably need to see a jsfiddle or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the text value when you're calling `text('0')`. To get the text value, you need to call the function without any paramters, as in `text()`. Try this:

```
if ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text() == "0") {
    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text('No');
} else if ($('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text() == "1") {
    $('.fsAction td:eq(2)').text('Yes');
}
```

Also, notice I changed the function for replacing the textual content from `html()` to `text()`. Since you're not actually putting in any HTML, `text()` is the better and faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-)

```
var elem = $('.fsAction td:eq(2)');
elem.text() == '0' ? str = 'No' : str = 'Yes';
elem.text(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but none of those appear to work,

I have multiple 1's and 0's which need replacing but they only change the first one thats to No, the first one is a 0